# String Fraction to Value in VBA

Tags: vba, type-conversion

How can fraction as a string be converted to a numeric value?

```
strFrac = "3/2"
```

Currently doing by splitting string to get numerator and denominator.

```
Dim x() As String
x = Split(strFrac, "/")
```

Then using `Val()` and dividing.

```
v = Val(x(0)) / Val(x(1))
```

result: v = 1.5

Is there a more direct approach?  Would be nice if something like `Val("3/2")` would work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Val` doesn't really *convert* a string into a numeric. It *stops reading a string when it encounters a non-numeric character*, and returns a `Double` representing the numeric value extracted from the string.

That "works" for your purposes, but the `CDbl` conversion function would be more appropriate.

If you're in Excel, [Scott's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44396399/1188513) leverages Excel's computing engine to literally `Evaluate` the string, which is what you're looking for. A side-effect of that is that the string can now contain Excel functions and cell references, and the result will still get evaluated.

If the evaluation returns an error value (e.g. `Evaluate("12/0")`), then you'll run into type issues if you assign the result directly to a `Double`. Instead, assign the result to a `Variant`, and validate that it's not returning an error using the `IsError` function - that will spare you from run-time error 13 / "type mismatch".

If you're not in Excel, you can't do that - and you don't want to reference the Excel object model just for that either - so your solution is indeed the simplest.

Comment: One issue with the OP's solution, though, is that it does not handle fractions such as "1 5/16".  This may not be an issue for the OP, but I mention it for completeness.

Comment: @BrianMStafford correct. OP's implementation is extremely naive! I guess it just "gets the job done" =)

Comment: @Brian, The use case is always a simple fraction ("numerator/denominator") as string.

Answer (score 6):

You want `Application.Evaluate`

```
Sub TEST()
Dim v As Double
Dim strFrac As String
strFrac = "3/2"
v = Application.Evaluate(strFrac)
Debug.Print v
End Sub
```

Comment: Leverages Excel's computing engine, so will also evaluate `"SUM(A:A)/SUM(B:B)"`. Quite possibly the simplest way to solve OP's problem. On the other hand... it ties the code to the Excel object model.

Comment: Will raise run-time error 13 on the assignment to `v` if `Evaluate` evaluates to an error value though ;-)